# Creating a symmetric frequency table in R

Tags: r

I have a problem that I think should be trivial, but I can't figure out an elegant solution to (or the right function to use).

Say I have a dataframe with two factor variables and I want to count their co-occurrences. This should be easy:

```
require(tidyverse)
set.seed(5)
example <- tibble(
  Var_1 = sample(letters[1:5], 50, replace = TRUE),
  Var_2 = sample(letters[1:4], 50, replace = TRUE)
)

table(example)
```

and the output is:

```
     Var_2
  Var_1 a b c d
      a 4 0 2 1
      b 3 4 2 3
      c 3 4 0 6
      d 3 5 2 0
      e 1 0 3 4
```

However, due to the fact that there are more unique factors in `Var_1` than `Var_2`, the table is asymmetric, `5` by `4` in this case. How would I force the table to be symmetric and use the longer vector of unique factors for both dimensions?

i.e., a `5` by `5` table in this example, something like this:

```
     Var_2
  Var_1 a b c d e
      a 4 0 2 1 0
      b 3 4 2 3 0
      c 3 4 0 6 0
      d 3 5 2 0 0
      e 1 0 3 4 0
```

The only thing I could think of is manually check which of the entries in `Var_1` don't appear in `Var_2` and append a column of zeros, but maybe there is a better solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `example` to `factors` with same `levels` for all the columns.

```
all_vec <- sort(unique(unlist(example)))
example[] <- lapply(example, factor, levels = all_vec)
table(example)

#     Var_2
#Var_1 a b c d e
#    a 4 0 2 1 0
#    b 3 4 2 3 0
#    c 3 4 0 6 0
#    d 3 5 2 0 0
#    e 1 0 3 4 0
```

---

If you want a `tidyverse` answer :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

example %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), factor, levels = all_vec)) %>%
  count(Var_1, Var_2, .drop = FALSE) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Var_1, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `xtabs` from `base R`

```
xtabs(val ~ ., cbind(transform(example, Var_2 = factor(Var_2, levels = letters[1:5])), val = 1))
#     Var_2
#Var_1 a b c d e
#    a 4 0 2 1 0
#    b 3 4 2 3 0
#    c 3 4 0 6 0
#    d 3 5 2 0 0
#    e 1 0 3 4 0
```